# Dynamic casting from text within plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Many tables in my database share a common layout, in particular they have a `serial` primary key named after the relation name. Updating these tables from within a web application often involves a query of the form:

```
UPDATE table SET attribute = x WHERE table_id = y
```

This is so common that I have a stored procedure that performs this task:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setvalue(
    relname text,
    row_id integer,
    colname text,
    newvalue text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET %I = $1 WHERE %I = $2', relname, colname, relname || '_id', colname) USING row_id;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for non-text types. For instance, updating a `date` column gives `ERROR: column ... is of type date but expression is of type text`. Assuming the text is a valid literal representation of the intended type, is there a safe way to get the DBMS to figure out the right type and do the right thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My own solution so far is to paste the string literal into the query:

```
EXECUTE format(
  'UPDATE %I SET %I = ' || quote_literal(newvalue) || ' WHERE %I = $1 ',
  relname, colname, relname || '_id') USING row_id;
```

or just

```
EXECUTE format(
  'UPDATE %I SET %I = %L WHERE %I = $1', 
  relname, colname, newvalue, relname || '_id') USING row_id;
```

This works for, e.g., appropriately formatted date types (`'1990-05-04'`). Probably this sacrifices being able to re-use query plan.